# How to access @PersistenceUnit private EntityManagerFactory emf in soaphandler

Tags: java, jpa, soap

I have implemented SOAPHandler, now in my handleMessage method i want to save SoapHeader into oracle database.

I got soapHeader like following

@Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

```
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

        System.out.println("\nOutbound message:");

    } else {

        System.out.println("\nInbound message:");

        try {
            SOAPMessage     soapMessage     =   context.getMessage();
            SOAPPart        soapPart        =   soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope    soapEnvelope    =   soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader      soapHeader      =   soapEnvelope.getHeader();

            SOAPBody        soapBody        =   soapEnvelope.getBody();
```

}

To save soapheader in DB using JPA i required entitymanagerfactory in soaphandler class. i try with @persistenceunit but it gives error that my soaphandler class not found in web application.

Regards,
imran

Comment: your question has insufficient information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a good idea to do DataBase manipulation in handler, i just parse soapheader and let it go to webservice and did database tasks in it.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 1):

You can store XML message in context, and then load it and save into DB in WebService:

*Handler:*

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
context.getMessage().writeTo(outputStream);
context.put("XML_MESSAGE_PARAM", outputStream.toString());
context.setScope("XML_MESSAGE_PARAM", Scope.APPLICATION);
```

*WebService:*

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext webContext;
String xmlMessage = (String) webContext.getMessageContext().get("XML_MESSAGE_PARAM");
```